# How can I go back to the initial opened buffer after :make in vim

Tags: vim, make

When I use make into vim, with `:make` it automatically jump to the first error, displaying a new buffer in the current tab if needed.

I use vim with multiple tabs, most of the time the error buffer is already opened in another tab. Because of that, using `:tabn` or `:tabp` doesn't work in my case. `:b#` either... And the previous buffer could be the non last edited one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to address this:

1. Use `:make!` and `vim` won't switch the buffer in the first place.
2. Set `switchbuf` to `useopen,usetab` and the implicit `:cf` will attempt to switch to an existing window or tab displaying the buffer.

Comment: switchbuf=usetab is exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try <kbd>CTRL-o</kbd>.

I use <kbd>CTRL-z</kbd> before `make`, then `fg` bring vim back.

Comment: I am using make inside vim